# Make own fluid template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need tis markup - left and right sidebars have static width (300px for example), and middle container must be fluid.

UPD: Sidebars are snapped to brovser sides

How can i do this with twitter-bootstrap(current version)?

Now i have this markup, but result is not what i need

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" style="width: 300px;">
        <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="span3" style="width: 300px;">
        <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario, we shall avoid using span class, so hat we may take control of the situation.

We shall create our own sidebar for this scenario.

like so:

Put this in your css.

```
.container-fluid > .sidebar-nav {
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     left:auto;
     width: 300px;
 }

 .left {
      float:left;
 }

 .right {
     float:right;
 }

 .container-fluid > .content {
     margin: 0 320px;
 }
```

Put this thml markup in your document.

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="sidebar-nav left">
            <div class="well">
            <h5>Sidebar</h5>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dianam Interposito brutis aeternae reversurus eum. Crescente mihi servitute meam ad nomine Maria cum magna aliter refundens domum Taliarchus eius in fuerat construeret cena reges. Tharsos determinatio vestes in lucem in fuerat est Apollonius. Navis fortiter invenit quasi nomen ibique parvulam eodem mulier. Denique laetare quod ait regem Boreas quam crucis in.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-nav right">
            <div class="well">
            <h5>Sidebar</h5>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dianam Interposito brutis aeternae reversurus eum. Crescente mihi servitute meam ad nomine Maria cum magna aliter refundens domum Taliarchus eius in fuerat construeret cena reges. Tharsos determinatio vestes in lucem in fuerat est Apollonius. Navis fortiter invenit quasi nomen ibique parvulam eodem mulier. Denique laetare quod ait regem Boreas quam crucis in.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dianam Interposito brutis aeternae reversurus eum. Crescente mihi servitute meam ad nomine Maria cum magna aliter refundens domum Taliarchus eius in fuerat construeret cena reges. Tharsos determinatio vestes in lucem in fuerat est Apollonius. Navis fortiter invenit quasi nomen ibique parvulam eodem mulier. Denique laetare quod ait regem Boreas quam crucis in.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

These codes shall output a page similar to this

[image: 3column layout]

Comment: I am just a newbie, and I am answering these type of questions since I am still training myself. Problem solving typing of thing. I am still far from being awesome. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

give width a percent.
**Updated** added `float:left;` to span6 so when you re-size the window the right div dont fall down

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" style="width: 20%;">
        <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6" style="width: 50%;float: left;">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="span3" style="width: 20%;">
        <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, idea is that sidebars must be with fixed width